# Invoke the createSession() method in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, drm

I am trying to create a MediaKeySession but I can't figure out how to invoke the createSession() method in JavaScript. Does anyone know how can I do this?

Comment: AFAIK "createSession()" isn't a thing unless you've defined it. Are you using a framework?

Comment: No. I read the specification at https://w3c.github.io/encrypted-media/ and I thought all those interfaces and methods are already implemented in the Chrome browser somehow. So I have to define my own objects and methods?

Comment: That's a proposal for a feature set, not documentation of actual features.